# How to calculate a confidence interval for the ratio of means of two small samples?

Tags: confidence-interval

Please explain clearly how to calculate a confidence interval for the ratio of means that were drawn from two small samples with non-normal distributions.

Comment: What assumptions are you making about these distributions?  And please tell us about the samples.  For instance, do they represent paired data or not?

Comment: Maybe bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap is a large-sample technique!